# KL divergence and the MAP approximation in BNNs

Tags: bayesian, kullback-leibler, divergence

I was reading this [blog post](https://www.uv.es/gonmagar/blog/2018/03/15/BayesianNeuralNetworks#map-variational-inference-relation) on bayesian neural networks, where the author shows that if we use as a variational distribution a product of delta function, then minimizing the loss function of a BNN is equivalent to minimize  the loss function of a standard neural network with a l2 regularization mechanism.
However, I have read that the Kl divergence is only defined between continuous distribution and not between discrete and continuous distribution, so I was wondering if the demonstration is still approximatively right or not and if not, what changes should be made. thanks

[image]